# Laravel unit test with input with array name

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

Input I am trying to fill:

```
<input type="text" id="order-number" name="order_numbers[]" class="form-control">
```

My unit test code:

```
    public function testSearch()
    {
        $this->actAsUser();
        $this->visit('/orders')
        ->type('12001546', 'order_numbers[]');
    }
```

Error I am getting:

```
1) OrdersTest::testSearch
InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field ""
```

Comment: how about `type('12001546', 'product_ids[]')` not `order_number[]`?

Comment: Sorry, I had wrong element in the first post, changed it and also fixed typo in unit test code which resulted in new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, couldn't find a better solution than

```
// TestCase.php
protected function storeArrayInput($values, $name)
{
     $this->inputs[$name] = $values;
     return $this;
}
```

---

```
// YourTest.php
public function testSearch()
{
    $this->actAsUser();
    $this->visit('/orders')
        ->storeArrayInput(['12001546'], 'order_numbers');
}
```